# How to correctly log in into AWS EC2 instance created by CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I'm just starting to play with AWS services, more specific with [CloudFormation](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1#/). I'm following some of the AWS tutorials, and so far so good, but I'm stuck at one thing: once I generate the template as follows:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
 Ec2Instance:
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties:
    InstanceType:
      Ref: InstanceTypeParameter1
    ImageId: ami-07d02ee1eeb0c996c
Parameters:
  InstanceTypeParameter1:
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues:
      - t2.micro
      - m1.small
      - m1.large
    Description: Choose the ec2 instance type
  myKeyPair: 
    Description: Amazon EC2 Key Pair
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
```

Once I upload the template, and click on **Next**, I can choose the **Amazon EC2 Key Pair** as you can see in the pict:

[Inputting the ssh key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbGjN.png)

And then I go to the EC2 console, I look the instance the CloudFromation just created, but I can't log-in using SSH protocol. As you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVwnE.png)

I would like to log in in my EC2 instances created by CloudFormation, I thought that using the myKeyPair parameter:

```
  myKeyPair: 
    Description: Amazon EC2 Key Pair
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
```

Would do the magic, but it doesn't. So: how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I find what did the trick:

As in the previously showed .yaml, in the **Parameters** section you need to ask for the user to select a *key* to use, with:

```
Parameters:
.........
  myKeyPair: 
    Description: Amazon EC2 Key Pair
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
```

What in fact led me to, when creating the Stack, the webpage prompt asking me for select one of the saved keys:
[image: Select one of the saved keys]

But I wasn't linking the collected *key* in the **Parameters** section with the **Resources** section... What I need to do is simply make a reference in the **Properties** section inside **Resource**, as follows:

```
Parameters:
.........
  myKeyPair: 
    Description: Amazon EC2 Key Pair
    Type: "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"

Resources:
.......
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
       ................
      KeyName:
        Ref: KeyName
       ................
```

That did the trick!!!